# Enviar datos sin que se actualice la pagina principal

Tags: php, java, html, mysql, jquery

Necesito mandar el `ID` sin que se recargue la pagina

`<a href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" >`

Comment: Para no recardar la pagina,  usa AJAX.

Comment: Y como le hago? xD

Comment: tengo  `<a href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" >` dentro de in while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras  con `Ajax` o con `fetch`

primero debes cambiar el `<a>` por :

```
<a href="#" onClick="callToCart('" <?php echo $fila['id']; ?> "')" >
```

con `ajax` (necesitas JQuery) :

```html
<script>

function callToCart(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"cart.php?id=" + id,
    async: false,
    success: data => {
      //esta es la respuesta, si necesitas una
       console.log(data)                     
   }
  });
  //con esto evitas que la pagina se recargue
  return false
}
</script>
```

Con `fetch` (no necesitas JQuery) :

```html
<script>
function callToCart(id){
 fetch("cart.php?id=" + id,)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) return response.text()
  })
  .then(function(html) {
    //aqui controlas la respuesta
    console.log(html)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    //aqui controlas si algo va mal
    console.log(err);
  });
  
  //aqui evitas que la pagina se recargue
  return false
}
</script>
```

**Nota:** si necesitas ver lo que el documento `cart.php` te devuelve. puedes verlo en la consola del navegador. para ello los `console.log()`